# About mt_rand of an array

Tags: php, random

I have a code which selects a random url from a folder like this:

```
<?php
  $urls = glob("videos/*.php");
  $random = mt_rand(0, count($urls) - 1);
  header ("location: ".$urls[$random]);
  exit;
?>
```

I had help with the $random function, but did not receive an explanation for it.

The code works perfectly. But I'm wondering why it looks like this:

```
mt_rand(0, count($urls) - 1);
```

Instead of this:

```
mt_rand(count($urls));
```

Comment: To clarify, would `mt_rand(count($urls));` work just as well as the other way?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [fine manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) first, and then ask questions. :)

But as You already did I will try to explain.

mt_rand function gives You random number. When no arguments given, it wloud return random number from set `[0,mt_getrandmax()]`. You do not need this.

If You wloud execute it like this: `mt_rand(count($urls))`, You would receive error like this:

> Warning: mt_rand() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in

What You need is value from range `[0,count($urls)-1]`, and this is what Your code does.

If You are wonderng about count($urls)-1 part, the count($ulrs) gives You the number of url, so if You have five of them, You will recive 5. But You need index of random url, and indexes in PHP begins at 0, so if You have five urls the last index of array will be 4.

Answer (score 0):

[mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) can be called with either no arguments, or two, but not one.

If called with two arguments, it will generate an integer number between these two values, and these two bounding values themselves are potential candidates as well:

> **min**
>      Optional lowest value to be returned
>   **max**
>      Optional highest value to be returned

Without arguments, the range is between 0 and some system dependent high natural number:

> If called without the optional min, max arguments mt_rand() returns a pseudo-random value between 0 and [mt_getrandmax()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-getrandmax.php).

This is different as in some other programming languages where without argument a **fractional** number is returned between 0 and (but not including 1).

Maybe you were thinking of *java.util.Random.nextInt()* which does accept one argument, and would work like you intended it, except that it is Java, and not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

No `mt_rand(count($urls));` will not work. 
And `mt_rand(0, count($urls));` will not *always* work as desired.

Explanation: `count($any_array)` will return lastIndex+1. For example

```
$a=array(10,20,30);
echo count($a); //3, but $a[3] is invalid
```

So you have the -1 bit. 
And mt_rand takes either 0 or 2 parameters.